# Gaussian kernel

Tags: math, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision

I was going through a Gaussian filter article and I suddenly came across this line `In theory, the Gaussian distribution is non-zero everywhere.` I gave it a couple of thoughts but couldn't satisfy myself. I would love to have others' opinions on it. Can someone explain to me in a simple term?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. The Gaussian kernel is related to the Gaussian PDF where it is only zero at infinity. Therefore it is impractical to have zeroes in the kernel as it requires infinite memory. Is this what you were after? If not please provide more details to your question.

Comment: @rayryeng yep, this is the answer that I was looking for. Actually, I had misinterpreted the statement. Now, it's clear that the distribution meant probability specifically. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of any number x in Gaussian Distribution is non-zero because of the way it's equation is designed.
[image]

f(x) will be very close to zero but still not zero for large x. Exp of a very large negative number is close to zero but not zero. In the graphs below, f(x) is asymptotic to x, not zero.
[image]